# Magento 2 - add a new step adding new form in checkout processes

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento-2.1

After following below procedures provided by Magento, both works properly if I implement them separately. However, I would like to combine both two tasks, which are adding a new step having a new input form on a checkout page.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/checkout/checkout_form.html 
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_step.html

Could you please give advice how to setup XML layout and modify knockout.js files?

Comment: Did you do it? Can you please share any findings